# Azure Functions on Linux - Install Additional Dependencies

Tags: linux, pdf, azure-functions, cross-platform, gdi

Running a C# Azure Functions app on a Premium Elastic Plan using Linux, leveraging some DevExpress libraries that help manipulate MS Office files and PDFs, which apparently depend on gdiplus and I cannot seem to get this thing resolved.

**We input the following via the Azure Portal for the Function App -> Configuration -> General settings -> Stack settings -> Startup Command:**

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y
> software-properties-common && sudo add-apt-repository 'deb
> http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main' && sudo apt-get update &&
> sudo apt-get install -y libc6-dev && sudo apt-get install -y
> libgdiplus && sudo apt-get install -y libicu-dev && sudo apt-get
> install -y libharfbuzz0b && sudo apt-get install -y libfontconfig1 &&
> sudo apt-get install -y libfreetype6 && sudo apt-get install -y
> libpango-1.0-0 && sudo apt-get install -y libpangocairo-1.0 && dotnet
> MyFunctionApp.dll

- *tried the above with and without sudo, made no difference, still get the exception below*
- *tried entering the above as wrapped in double quotes and prefixed with -c in case it mattered (as that gets passed to docker run command), no difference*

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The type
> initializer for 'DevExpress.Text.Fonts.GDIFontSubstitutionEngine'
> threw an
> exception.","ExceptionType":"System.TypeInitializationException","StackTrace":"
> at
> DevExpress.Pdf.ContentGeneration.PdfExportFontManager.GetMatchingFont(PdfSetTextFontCommand
> setTextFontCommand)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.PdfInteractiveFormField.GetFontInfo(IPdfExportFontProvider
> fontSearch)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.Native.PdfTextBasedFormFieldAppearanceBuilder`1..ctor(PdfWidgetAnnotation
> widget, T formField, IPdfExportFontProvider fontSearch, PdfRgbaColor
> backgroundColor)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.Native.PdfWidgetAppearanceBuilderFactory.DevExpress.Pdf.Native.IPdfInteractiveFormFieldVisitor.Visit(PdfTextFormField
> formField)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.PdfWidgetAnnotation.CreateAppearanceBuilder(IPdfExportFontProvider
> fontSearch)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.PdfAnnotation.EnsureAppearance(PdfAnnotationAppearanceState
> appearanceState, PdfDocumentStateBase documentState, PdfForm form)\n
> at
> DevExpress.Pdf.PdfWidgetAnnotation.EnsureAppearance(PdfDocumentStateBase
> documentState)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.Native.PdfDocumentStateBase.CreateFormData(PdfInteractiveFormField
> field)\n   at
> DevExpress.Pdf.Native.PdfDocumentStateBase.CreateFormData()\n
>
> ,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has
> occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw
> an
> exception.","ExceptionType":"System.TypeInitializationException","StackTrace":"
> at
> System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipNewInstalledFontCollection(IntPtr&
> fontCollection)\n   at
> DevExpress.Text.Fonts.GDIFontSubstitutionEngine.CreateFromGDIPlus()\n
> at
> DevExpress.Text.Fonts.GDIFontSubstitutionEngine..cctor()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
> error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"U**nable to load shared library
> 'libgdiplus' or one of its dependencies.** In order to help diagnose
> loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:
> liblibgdiplus: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory","ExceptionType":"System.DllNotFoundException","StackTrace":"
> at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token,
> StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)\n   at
> System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()"}}}

Any ideas? I cannot install WSL on this machine to debug locally either. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: You should use Open XML SDK for manipulating Office files, and look for PDF libraries/sdk that are compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: Sorry @AnandSowmithiran that's a really ignorant comment; there are many great options for working with Office files, and the one we are using, DevExpress is of course .Net Core compatible and cross-platform. The issue is that on Linux, an additional dependency is required and I am having trouble installing it within the Azure Functions environment. https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/401730/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/use-the-devexpress-cross-platform-drawing-engine?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T980115&contactId=A2145307

Answer (score 0):

Well this turned out to be quite a lot of fun. The Startup Command input has since been removed from the app config settings in the Azure portal UI, presumably because it just wasn't working. Indeed, the only way to get this done was to use a custom image.

Here's the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot -c Release


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0-appservice
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main" \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libc6 -f -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0 \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        libgdiplus \
        libicu-dev \
        libharfbuzz0b \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libfreetype6 \
        libpango-1.0-0 \
        libpangocairo-1.0 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```